# Disable grouping and re-ordering in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

From my data I want to draw points, one point per record, in the same way the records are in the table, without re-ordering them. For this example table:

```
dt <- data.table(titles=factor(c('B','C','A','C')),
                 values=c(1,2,3,4) )
```

I want to have the following plot:
[image: sample plot]

So far I have to use the following code to do this:

```
ggplot(data = dt, 
       aes(x=seq_len(nrow(dt)), y=values)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=dt$titles) + xlab('titles')
```

But I really don't like it: 1) all that mess with `x=seq_len(nrow(...))` looks ugly, 2) I have to address `dt` explicitly in `scale_x_discrete`. What would be correct way to draw a plot like this?

Comment: Since you don't really want to treat `titles` as a factor nor do you want to "collapse" identical values (i.e. you have two records that correspond to "C"), what you suggested actually looks pretty sensible to me. AFAIK - `scale_x_XXX` does not inherit from `aes()` so you need to explicitly address `dt$` when invoking it. Or, define it outside the plotting code, but that's basically the same as what you've done above.

Comment: ok, I see, thanks for your input! I have nothing against treating titles as a factor, just wanted to keep their order. Actually my question combined two independent issues: how to disable re-ordering of `titles` and how to disable "collapsing".

Comment: P.S. I got another issue with this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482095/