# label only subset of points in a ggplot where x was modified

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this kind of table:

```
dt <- data.table(titles=c('B','C','A','C'),
                 labs  =c('b','c','a','c'),
                 values=c( 3, 2, 3, 4))
```

In order to plot the points without collapsing and re-ordering, I had to do the following trick with `ggplot()`: instead of `aes(x=titles, y=values)` I use `aes(x=seq_len(nrow(dt)), y=values)`:

```
ggplot(data = dt, 
       aes(x=seq_len(nrow(dt)), y=values)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label=labs)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=dt$titles) + xlab('titles')
```

Now I want to have labels not for all points but only for a subset of them (for example, where `values>2`). This call doesn't work:

```
ggplot(data = dt, 
       aes(x=seq_len(nrow(dt)), y=values)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data=subset(dt, values>2), aes(label=labs)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=dt$titles) + xlab('titles')
 # Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2): label, x, y
```

How to call `geom_text()` in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `inherit.aes=F` option:

```
dt2 <- subset(dt, values>2)
ggplot(data = dt, 
       aes(x=seq_len(nrow(dt)), y=values)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data=dt2, aes(x=values, y=values, label=labs), inherit.aes=F) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=dt$titles) + xlab('titles')
```

Comment: well, `x=values` does a bad job here (I have slightly modified `values` in my example to make it visible). But with `x=which(dt$values>2)` it works OK